# Actionscript 3 - Access of undefined property error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, event-handling, tween

In my timeline, I have a 'background' layer, an 'actions' layer and a 'play' layer (all have just 1 frame). The background layer has a MovieClip called backgroundMC and when you double click the MovieClip, there is a MovieClip called analysisScreenMC. In the timeline for analysisScreenMC, there is a folder called 'Title Bar' and inside 'Title Bar' there is a layer called 'answers' which has a motion tween which makes analysisScreenMC fade out to 50% in a span on 15 frames.

The 'play' layer just has a MovieClip called playButton.

Now, when playButton is clicked, I want to play analysisScreenMC so that it fades out. Here is what I tried.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flashx.textLayout.formats.Float;

function playButtonClicked(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    analysisScreenMC.play();
}

playButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playButtonClicked);
```

when I run this, it gives me an error saying 'Access of undefined property analysisScreenMC.'

Any idea on how to fix this?

Note: I am using Adobe Flash CS 5 and Actionscript 3.

Edit: When I put

```
trace("backgroundMC="+ backgroundMC+", backgroundMC.analysisScreenMC="+ backgroundMC.analysisScreenMC);
```

inside the

```
function playButtonClicked
```

this is what it traces

```
backgroundMC=[object analysisScreenInside_1], backgroundMC.analysisScreenMC=[object MovieClip]
```

analysisScreenMC is the instance name of analysisScreenInside

Comment: Is the code you shared located on the actions layer?

Comment: @SlyRaskal yes the code is in the actions layer in the main timeline. How do I tell it that analysisScreenMC is inside the background layer / inside backgroundMC?

Comment: Please verify that you have accurately described the hierarchy of your MovieClips.  The example I created on my machine for the answer I posted based on your description worked fine on my computer, which leads me to believe that there may be something that needs more clarification.

Comment: @SlyRaskal main timeline there is 'actions' layer, 'playButton' layer and 'background' layer, in that order (from top to bottom). All three only have one frame. Actions layer has what I posted above in the question.  playButton layer has playButtonMC. Background layer has backgroundMC. Inside backgroundMC, there is analysisScreenMC, which is has actions layer consisting of 1 frame and an 'answers' layer. Actions layer just has 'stop();'. 'answers' layer is a motion tween which makes analysisScreenMC fade out. You can also click inside analysisScreenMC to view a bitmap image. Does that matter?

Comment: @SlyRaskal can you post the example you created on your machine? Or would it be possible for you to upload it so I can download it?

Comment: @SlyRaskal okay turns out all I needed to do was change backgroundMC.analysisScreenMC.play(); to backgroundMC.play();.... You can update your answer and I will mark this as solved.

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code.  I dupcliated your file on my system and this code appears to work just fine.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flashx.textLayout.formats.Float;

function playButtonClicked(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    backgroundMC.play();
}

playButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playButtonClicked);
```

The key here is that your reference to the location of where `analysisScreenMC` is located was incorrect.

Comment: Hm, I tried this and now it just keeps on playing the animation over and over again even when I didn't click anything.

Comment: That's an easy fix.  Simply create an actions layer in the `analysisScreenMC` and on that actions layer put a `stop();` call on frame 1, or whatever frame you need to based on your anaimation.

Comment: Remember, timelines are independent of each other when it comes to MovieClips, so you have to treat them carefully when it comes to understanding how movieclips behave in respect to each other.  Think of timelines like procedural programming. It makes it much easier to understand then.

Comment: right, but  when I put stop() in the analysisScreenMC actions layer and run the flash animation, nothing happens even when I click the play button.

Comment: Also, see my edit to the post, it might help solve this issue.

Comment: Your updated information and the trace information leads me to believe that you may have a separate issue than you originally described/thought you had.  Can you verify the *instance* name of the MovieClip that is on the 'background' layer.

Comment: the instance name of the MovieClip on the background layer is backgroundMC